# .NET Core is not listed

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I wanted to create a new ASP.NET Core app targeting the new .NET Core 1.0.

First, in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I don't see .NET Core listed
[image]

And this is what I'm seeing in project.json file. Looks like I'm targeing dotnet5.6
[image]

Is it safe to assume this is all correct?

And if this is correct, could it possibly be more confusing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pulldown has no meaning for .NET Core projects as it doesn't use it. Only what's in project.json matters for .NET Core / .xproj projects.

`netcoreapp1.0` target framework moniker (short TFM) is .NET Core project for executables (ASP.NET Web Application or .NET Core Console Application). `netstandard1.x` (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) matrix for api surface of netstandard TFM) is for class libraries.

The `import` section just tells nuget to also restore packages which target `dotnet5.6` (old TFM for .NET Core Library, which is now replaced with `netstandard1.x`) and `portable-net45-win8`, which are also compatible with .NET Core. These allow you to install packages which are compatible but are not yet repackaged for `netstandard1.x`.